# Cannot get font awesome icon to line up next to username

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, font-awesome

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I am trying to get my font awesome icon to line up just to the right of the 'username'.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="vue-dropdown">
  <div>
    USERNAME
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-caret-right"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="options"><a href="/admin" target="_blank">Admin</a><a href="/impersonate/search/" target="_blank">Impersonate</a></div>
</div>
```

I have some CSS set to rotate the icon to face down when the dropdown menu is displayed - but the icon appears under the username.

```
.vue-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 125px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px #c3c3c3;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 11em;
  height: auto;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.options a {
  background-color: white;
  color: black!important;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.options a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.vue-dropdown:hover .options {
  display: block;
}

.vue-dropdown:hover .icon-caret-right {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.vue-dropdown .icon-caret-right {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

I have a [fiddle of it here](https://jsfiddle.net/hannylicious/knfxvw96/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/knfxvw96/2/ - if this works for you, I'll put it on the record as an answer and you can give me the good karma.
**Edit:** https://jsfiddle.net/knfxvw96/4/ to address the dropdown alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the display from block to inline block like below(working fiddle attached).

```
.vue-dropdown:hover .icon-caret-right {
  display: inline-block;
}

.vue-dropdown .icon-caret-right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/knfxvw96/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/derrysan7/knfxvw96/1/

Just wrap `USERNAME` in `span` tag, add `display:inline-block`, and then add `display:inline-block` to the icon's `i` tag